# Why converting to int the Process Id in Condor doesn't work this way?

Tags: bash, variables, condor

So I have the following HTCondor submit description that works:

```
n = $(ProcId) + 1
arguments = read_$INT(n).fa
```

Why can't I do this instead?

```
n = $INT($(ProcId) + 1)
arguments = read_${n}.fa
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using this (bash script, submit file, ClassAd, ...) and what error do you get when using the second variant?

Comment: None of the code snippets you mentioned will work in bash. Also, what exact errors / behaviour do you have ?

Comment: this is a submit condor file. The error is: WARNING: the line 'n = $INT($(ProcId) + 1)' was unused by condor_submit. Is it a typo?

Comment: Basically I just need a variable that starts from 1 so I thought of using ProcId in the condor_submit file, but unfortunately it starts from 0. I already got it working with the first version, but then I have to convert to INT every single time (in the output files, etc) so I was looking for a simpler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTCondor [submit description files](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/v9_0/man-pages/condor_submit.html#submit-description-file-commands) use their own format for substitutions, not bash/shell syntax.

> #### Macros
>
> Parameterless macros in the form of `$(macro_name:default initial value)` may be used anywhere in HTCondor submit description files to provide textual substitution at submit time. Macros can be defined by lines in the form of
>
> ```
> <macro_name> = <string>
> ```

In order to refer to a macro (variable) `n` use `$(n)` instead of the bash syntax `${n}`. Since macros cannot be nested, evaluating `$INT` based on another macro requires an intermediate variable:

```
proc1 = $(ProcId) + 1
n = $INT(proc1)
arguments = read_$(n).fa
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Unfortunately I still have this error: Submitting job(s)ERROR at Queue statement on Line 35: $INT() macro: $(ProcId does not evaluate to an integer!

Comment: @Caterina You're right, my bad. Macros cannot be nested. Updated it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Gonna include you in my acknowledgements for this project ;)